# Pass URL alias info to default value of Webform field

Tags: webforms, path-aliases

I'm running the Storm (project management) module and for each task, the user needs to fill out a form regarding information about the task, including uploading images about certain information captured in the form. I'm trying to pass the url alias from the task page to the default value of a field I created in webform. My current URL's look like this: `?q=content/82245940-initial-services`
. My problem (well, at least my first problem) is that I use the `%get[q]` but get `node/5` as the default value. I don't understand and know enough about PHP programming yet, to know how to fix this so that I get `82245940-initial-services` as the default value instead. Any help is much appreciated for the noobie. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** By the way I have read these posts that while I have found helpful to understand the general concept, the details are over my head:

http://drupal.org/node/296453#webform-url-default

http://drupal.org/node/228622

So, I've tried, I just don't know enough yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the URI with `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` and remove the "q=content/" string from it.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of a way to remove the "q=content/" string from it? Is there a resource that you know of that I could read up on?

Comment: str_replace("q=content/", "", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) should do the trick